# Forgot to change Name Servers before transfer -- NS Record not updating

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

On February 19th I transferred a domain from GoDaddy to Route 53.

In my own ignorance I didn't change the NS records beforehand. As I understand it, Route53 should have taken over as the authoritative name server within a couple of days. It's been approximately 5 days, and I still am unable to do any DNS queries.. GoDaddy's name servers are still listed under some WhoIs lookups... but they've removed my DNS zone config, so there are no records to return.

On Route53 I have: NS, SOA and one A record.

Is there anything else that could be going on here? Shouldn't SOMETHING have my new NS record? Google nameservers and opendns name servers both do not return any authoritative or unauthoritative responses using dig.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> As I understand it, Route53 should have taken over as the authoritative name server within a couple of days.

No, Route 53 should have taken over as *registrar*.  Changing registrars doesn't change the authoritative name servers.

In the Route 53 console, click "Registered Domains."

Select your domain.

Choose "add/edit name servers."

Enter the correct values for the Route 53 name servers, which you'll see when you click on the domain from the Hosted Zones page.

Comment: Yeah, I though there might be a facepalm moment when you saw the solution. :)

Comment: Thanks, I must add that this is in a separate location from the managed zone (first page for the domain), and after updating the changes, refresh the page to see your update.